# Прижать элемент к низу экрана, если нету прокрутки

Tags: html, css, javascript

Добрый день.
Можно каким-то образом сделать такое?

Есть элемент (див), он должен быть всегда прижат к нижней части экрана либо нижней части страницы, если есть вертикальная прокрутка.

Любые идеи?

Comment: йоу, чувак, вопросу 5 лет. какой дубль :D

Comment: @DenisMasster Тут играет роль практичность, а не время. Более подробно [здесь](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3312/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот](http://dimox.name/press_footer_bottom_with_css/) несколько примеров как прижать футер к низу страницы без JS. По аналогии можно прижать любой блок.

Comment: спасибо) будем знать

Comment: @Barton Как вы, наверное, знаете, ответы-ссылки здесь не приветствуются. Перенесите с третьестороннеего ресурса код в ваш ответ.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov к сожалению не знаю, это было 3,5 года назад и копипастить смысла не вижу и не буду. Человек спросил совета, я привел ссылку с примерами. Его это устроило.

Comment: @Barton Я часто редактирую ответы даже с десяткой плюсов. Обратите внимание, что этот вопрос просмотрели почти 10 тысяч человек. Эта информация не только для одного человека, который спросил, а для многих людей. Поэтому перенесите знания сюда. Может вы получите ещё больше плюсов, улучшив ваш ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#footer { position: relative; top: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет ребят, то что я хотел в конечном счете выглядит вот так:

```
<div id='container'> Основная часть сайта </div>
<div id='bottom'> Низ </div>

var forCenteredBottom=($(document).width()/2)-($('#bottom').width()/2);

if($('#container').height() + $('#bottom').height() < $(window).height() ){
    $('#bottom').css({
        position:'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        left: forCenteredBottom
    })
}else{
    $('#bottom').css({
        position:'relative'
    })
}
```

В результате чего если при загрузке страницы сумма контейнера и боттома меньше чем вся высота окна, то боттом цепляется в низ экрана. Если больше, значит оставляем боттом как есть, и спокойно прокручиваем страницу.

Comment: ого какую дичь я писал 4 года назад!

Answer (score 2):

Еще посоветовал бы вам добавить повторение вашей функции при изменении разрешения экрана. Например, пользователь вашего сайта зашел с планшета, все загрузилось, и тут он повернул планшет в альбомный вид. Тогда ваша разметка слетит, нужно чтобы при изменении разрешения ещё раз проверялась функция. На Jquery это делается так:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    //здесь ваша функция
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="bottomdiv">Этот див всегда в низу</div>
<style>
#bottomdiv{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Зачем писать `0px`? Просто `0`