# Растянутый футер

Tags: html, css

У меня на сайте футер не прижат к низу окна. Это просто блок с выстой 50px. Как сделать, чтобы если блок не дотрагивался до низа окна, то он бы растягивался. Т.е. сейчас у меня идет фон-футер-фон. А надо фон-футер.
Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Был подобный вопрос. Может здесь найдете решение: [прижать элемент к низу экрана, если нету прокрутки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/108495/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8).