# Как сделать резиновую высоту?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Как сделать блок резиновым по высоте? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Дубль 2**

Надеюсь поможет, **[ловите](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/Z99Dp/)**.

-150 - это отступ с верху у элемента header(50px), + высота элемента header(50px), + высота элемента footer (50px).

Удачи.

**P.s.** Когда будете адаптировать на свой макет, не забывайте учитывать все margin и padding.

Answer (score 1):

Был подобный вопрос. Воспользуйтесь поиском. Может здесь найдете решение: [прижать элемент к низу экрана, если нету прокрутки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/108495/javascript-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Answer (score -1):

Любой div блок по умолчанию тянется по высоте.
Значение высоты height прописывать просто не нужно.